# Multiple monitor display settings change after Windows reboot

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I'm running Windows7 x64, and everytime I restart my computer, my multiple monitor settngs change. The monitors flip around, my 30" LCD goes to a different resolution, the task bar moves around, and my desktop icons move to a different monitor.

After I correct the problem, I reboot, and for a few seconds the login screen shows on the correct monitor, it flickers, and then the wrong settings get applied.

This problem only started happening after I installed UltraMon. I uninstalled ultramon hoping it would fix the issue, but no dice.

I've already deleted my graphics card driver, reran a driver cleaner, and reinstalled my graphics drivers, and it didn't help.

I've fixed this issue before by deleting a few registry keys, but for the life of me I can't remember what the keys were, nor can I remember the search query I used to find them in the first place.

Edit to add:

- I have a Nvidia Geforce 285GTX
- Running: 266.58
- Not on a domain.
- 30" LCD on Duallink-DVI
- 24" LCD on Single-link DVI

Here is what happened: I installed UltraMon, setup 2 profiles: a single monitor display (for when I use my big monitor for my laptop), and a dual monitor display. I set my monitor to single display, used my laptop, then rebooted windows on my desktop. At this point windows started reconfiguring my profile on startup/restart to always make my small monitor the "main display" (which it is in single monitor profile). I uninstalled ultramon, and it didn't fix this issue. Sometime went by, and I made a system image with Acronis. Some more time went by and I decided to fix the monitor issue.

On windows (at least windows 7), when you make changes to your display configuration, this configuration is stored in the Registry. I know this with 100% certainty because deleting this display keys solved this issue before. I fixed this by deleting the display configuration that is stored in the registry.

Now, yesterday I reimaged my machine using that acronis system image, and of course, now my monitors are screwy once again. I'm trying to remember what the registry keys are so I can clean them out (and of course make a new image :))

Comment: which graphics card and driver version you have plz specify.

Comment: Yeah, this is not a common problem and is probably specific to your configuration.  What are the graphics cards you're using?  What are the monitors and how are the monitors cabled to the machine?  Are you on a domain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration\

Clear out all the values in there, and reboots